# How to take the property from entity

Tags: php, symfony

I have two entities 'status' and 'doctor'. Every doctor can add a status in his profile. When the doctor wants to add a status, he can add status for another doctor because of the choice field .

It's not logic, I want that every doctor add only his status, not for other doctor.

How can I fix it ?

This is the status form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder

        ->add('medecin','entity',array('class'=>'DoctorBundle:medecin','property'=>'prenom','multiple'=>false))
        ->add('text')
        ->add('description')
        ->add('image',new ImageType())
    ;
}`
```

Comment: You have to add a relation OneToOne in the ORM between Doctor and Status

Comment: but the doctor can add one or many status

Comment: How does `DoctorBundle:medecin` fits in all this? We know of `status` and `doctor` but what about `medecin`? Can you show us the entities?

Comment: ` /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DoctorBundle\Entity\statut", mappedBy="medecin", cascade={"remove", "persist"})
     */
    protected $statut;`

Comment: medecin (french) its the entity doctor

Comment: Oh, right, sorry about that :)

Comment: I've added an answer. See if that helps a bit :)

Comment: i remove the choice field (medecin) from status and i modify the create form and newAction in status controller, i can add statut but the medecin_id still null i thing use the method get to get medecin id or what ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the field Doctor (medecin for you) from the Form and then in the controller when you are handling the form response just do this

```
    if ('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {
        $statusForm->handleRequest($request);
        if ($statusForm->isValid()) {
            $status = $statusForm->getData();

            $status->setDoctor($this->getUser());

            $statusManager->flush($status);
        }
    }
```

$this->getUser() if you're logged in with the doctor, if you're not, get him however you are doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based on your comments I think you have several ways to tackle this:

1. Remove `medecin` form field altogether and assign it later. For example:

   ```
   $status = ....; // Your entity
   $currentDoctor = ... // logic for getting myself :)
   $status->setMedecin($currentDoctor);

   $form = $this->createForm(StatusType(), $status);
   $form->handleRequest($request);
   if ( $form->isValid() ){


       // The rest is the same
   }
   ```
2. Bind `data` attribute of `medecin` form field. This further complicates things as you need to pass yourself (`currentDoctor`) into the form type. I would definitely go for #1 above.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I have this code in my status controller of create form:

```
/**
 * Creates a form to create a statut entity.
 *
 * @param statut $entity The entity
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
 */
private function createCreateForm(statut $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new statutType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('statut_create'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

    return $form;
}
```

`

Comment: i must change the create form of status or newAction ?

Comment: No, I mean that this seems like an additional info of your question, hence, it belongs up there. Just edit the question and paste this up ;)

Answer (score 0):

i try this code its OK with the choice field but the Doctor-id take the value null, this is the code create form:`$id= $entity->setMedecin();
        $form = $this->createForm(new statutType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('statut_create'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));`